# How to plot on the same object returned by a pandas histogram plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have created a Pandas DataFrame and plotted it using `.hist()`.

I want to be able to draw lines/curves on top of the same figure.

How can I do that?

I was able to plot my data as a histogram using `df.hist(column='Example', bins=15)`. This assigns the returned object to `axis`.

I thought I might be able to plot a line using `ax=axis` as an argument. But this isn't valid.

It appears that `plt.plot` takes different `kwargs` to `DataFrame.hist`. Multiple sets of data from a DataFrame can be plot on the same figure, as histograms, using `.hist()` in combination with an argument of `ax=axis`.

Here is some example code, taken from a Jupyter Notebook, plus some data to play with.

```
data = [211995, 139950, 202995, 223000, 184995, 82000, 127000, 240000, 116000, 74500, 151000, 149000, 290000, 146000, 174500, 418000, 150000, 150000, 260000, 100000, 282500, 510000, 142000, 382000, 220000, 259000, 330000, 177500, 290000, 280000, 118000, 97000, 124000, 385000, 199950, 90000, 135000, 395000, 182000, 105000, 80000, 230000, 227950, 176995, 110000, 142000, 132500, 100000, 95000, 257500, 186000, 230000, 169995, 167995, 119950, 119950, 361000, 125000, 242000, 240000, 205000, 187500, 180000, 146000, 257995, 380000, 144995, 139995, 159995, 265000, 288000, 288000, 162500, 290000, 182737, 235000, 250000, 175000, 153000, 125000, 170000, 165000, 187995, 250000, 220000, 108750, 125000, 245000, 100000, 130000, 115000, 218000, 190000, 435000, 300000, 465000, 179950, 259500, 187000, 200000]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)
df.columns = ['Example']

axis = df.hist(column='Example', bins = 15)

x = numpy.linspace(1e5, 5e5, 20)

def f(x):
    return x * numpy.exp(-x)

y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y, axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The following explains how to use the object returned by a pandas histogram plot, to plot into a specific `axes`.
- There are three pandas plotting methods for creating a histogram:

  1. [`pandas.DataFrame.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), which returns *`matplotlib.AxesSubplot` or `numpy.ndarray` of them*
  2. [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html), which returns *`matplotlib.AxesSubplot`*
  3. [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='hist'`, which returns *`matplotlib.axes.Axes` or `numpy.ndarray` of them*

  - The pandas plotting API is very versitile, so it's recommended to always check the type of object returned by the plot.
- It is better to use the [explicit `axes` interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface), than to switch to the [implict `pyplot` interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface), as per [Why be explicit?](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit)

  - [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) doesn't have an `ax` parameter, and will only draw onto the current `axes`.
  - [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) draws onto the specified `axes` object.
  - In the case of the following examples, [`plt.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) and [`Axes.axhline`](https://matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline) were used for convenience.

### Data and Imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns  # for data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

  species     island  bill_length_mm  bill_depth_mm  flipper_length_mm  body_mass_g     sex
0  Adelie  Torgersen            39.1           18.7              181.0       3750.0    Male
1  Adelie  Torgersen            39.5           17.4              186.0       3800.0  Female
2  Adelie  Torgersen            40.3           18.0              195.0       3250.0  Female
3  Adelie  Torgersen             NaN            NaN                NaN          NaN     NaN
4  Adelie  Torgersen            36.7           19.3              193.0       3450.0  Female
```

### `df.hist`

```py
axes = df.hist(['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm'])

# draws first axes
axes[0][0].axhline(y=30, c='r')

# draws on second axes
axes[0][1].axhline(y=30, c='purple')

# only drawn an the last plot
plt.axhline(y=20, c='k')
```

```py
# returns an array of axes
axes
[out]:
array([[<Axes: title={'center': 'bill_length_mm'}>, <Axes: title={'center': 'bill_depth_mm'}>]], dtype=object)
```

[image]

```py
# with only a single column
axes = df.hist('bill_length_mm')

# index to the axes
axes[0][0].axhline(y=30, c='r')

# switching to the implicit interface works, but is not the recommended way
plt.axhline(y=20, c='k')
```

```py
# still an array with a single axes
axes
[out]:
array([[<Axes: title={'center': 'bill_length_mm'}>]], dtype=object)
```

[image]

### `df.plot.hist`

#### Single `axes`

```py
ax = df['bill_length_mm'].plot.hist()

# or
ax = df.plot.hist()

# or
ax = df.plot.hist(y='bill_length_mm')

# plot on the axes
ax.axhline(y=30, c='k')
```

```py
# returns a single axes
ax
[out]:
<Axes: ylabel='Frequency'>
```

#### Array of `axes`

```py
axes = df.plot.hist(by='sex')

# draws first axes
axes[0].axhline(y=30, c='r')

# draws on second axes
axes[1].axhline(y=30, c='purple')

# only drawn an the last plot
plt.axhline(y=20, c='k')
```

```py
# returns an array of axes
axes
[out]: 
array([<Axes: title={'center': 'Female'}, ylabel='Frequency'>, <Axes: title={'center': 'Male'}, ylabel='Frequency'>], dtype=object)
```

### `df.plot(kind='hist')`

#### Single `axes`

```py
ax = df['bill_length_mm'].plot(kind='hist')

# or
ax = df.plot(kind='hist')

# or
ax = df.plot(kind='hist', y='bill_length_mm')

# plot on the axes
ax.axhline(y=30, c='k')
```

```py
# returns a single axes
ax
[out]: 
<Axes: ylabel='Frequency'>
```

#### Array of `axes`

```py
axes = df.plot(kind='hist', by='sex')

# draws first axes
axes[0].axhline(y=30, c='r')

# draws on second axes
axes[1].axhline(y=30, c='purple')

# only drawn an the last plot
plt.axhline(y=20, c='k')
```

```py
# returns an array of axes
axes
[out]:
array([<Axes: title={'center': 'Female'}, ylabel='Frequency'>, <Axes: title={'center': 'Male'}, ylabel='Frequency'>], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just this. Apparently the axis kwarg is not required.

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

---

Full example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)
df.columns = ['Example']

axis = df.hist(column='Example', bins = 15)

x = numpy.linspace(1e5, 5e5, 20)

def f(x):
    return 1.0e-5 * x * numpy.exp(-1.0e-5 * x)

y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```